# Calling mysql_fetch_assoc only returns first result, even when called multiple times (CLOSED: TYPO)

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: Phil's comment on making the `MySQL_query` into a variable instead of running it through the while loop was the correct answer!

I'm am trying to print out all the items in an item table using the MySQL_fetch_assoc operator. It only returns the first result even when called in a while loop, but when called through the command line running, it returns all of the correct results. I have tried to run the while command without the`$numRows > 0` conditional but then it just returns an infinite array with only the first result.

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM item JOIN seller ON item.seller_id = seller.seller_id;";
$numRows = MySQL_num_rows(MySQL_query($query));
while ($numRows > 0 && $row = MySQL_fetch_assoc(MySQL_query($query))) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["item_name"] . "</td>\n" .
" <td>" . $row["category"] . "</td>\n" .
" <td>" . $row["item_price"] . "</td>\n" .
" <td>" . $row["user_email"] . </td>\n" .
" </tr>\n";
$numRows--;
...
```

It should be return a table of all the items

```
Name Category Price Seller Email
cup  utensils 200  bob@email.com
shaker utensils 300 sam@email.com
spoon  utensils 400 james@email.com
```

but only returns a table with the first result

```
Name Category Price Seller Email
cup  utensils 200   bob@email.com
cup  utensils 200   bob@email.com
cup  utensils 200   bob@email.com
```

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yea i do know that, but I think that the school's servers are still using a PHP version <= 5.5 because when I try to supplement MySQLI_ it does not return anything.

Comment: You're re-running the same query. You need to only call `mysql_query()` **once** and save the result into a variable.

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much! That was the correct answer! I don't know how to make that comment the correct answer though!

Comment: @Spikes don't worry about it. This question should be closed as as *"typo"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is creating a new resource on each iteration with the `MySQL_query($query)` expression, and as such when you call `MySQL_fetch_assoc(MySQL_query($query))` you are always receiving the first row of the query.

A solution to this would to create the resource before the while loop, and then call `MySQL_fetch_assoc()` on that resource.

Eg:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM item JOIN seller ON item.seller_id = seller.seller_id;";
$res = MySQL_query($query)
$numRows = MySQL_num_rows($res); // You can also modify this line
while ($numRows > 0 && $row = MySQL_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    ...
}
```

As Obsidian Age also said, you should consider moving to MySQLi or PDO. MySQLi is particularly painless to transfer to if all your code is using the older MySQL functions.

Comment: *"MySQLi is particularly painless"* <- possibly one of the worst pieces of advice and yet it seems so prevalent. The PDO API is **so much simpler** to use, you'd think it would be the default choice for newbie devs but due to posts like this, it is not

Comment: Also, this question didn't really need an answer

Comment: ^ Isn't that subjective? I've personally found MySQLi easier to work with than PDO :) But maybe that's due to the contrasting amount of time I've spent working with the two :P

Comment: @ObsidianAge I suppose. How's that parameter binding with arrays going by the way? ;)

Comment: It's probably so prevalent because the [MySQLi manual has similar sentiments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) about transferring from MySQL to MySQLi. If someone is familiar with the MySQL family of functions, then the procedural style of MySQLi is easy to pick up.